# Show a title in font- awesome Icons

Tags: css, html, font-awesome

I would like to know if it is possible to show a text / title when the mouse is over a font-awesome icon

```css
.title {
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="title"><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2xfa fa-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Comment: Can you use `title="Our Blog"`  ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include sample code you have tried?

Comment: <div class="title"><span title="fa-exchange"><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2xfa fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps with a data-attribute in an `:after` pseudo-element

[**attr() @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

```css
.fa {
  position: relative;
}

.fa:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding-left: .25em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: .5em;
  color: red;
}

div {
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-title="Exchange"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, you can use the native `title` attribute on the `i`:

`<i class="..." title="My title here"></i>`

When you hover over an attribute with `title` then you get a little popup with the text.

Is this the effect you are after?

```css
div {
 color: green;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2xfa fa-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" title="My title"></i></div>
```